# List between 2 ranges and n elements in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, controls, discrete-mathematics, discretization

How can i create a list of numbers that it will be a serie?
for example function(0, 2, 5) from 0 to 2 with 5 elements --> [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]
Is there any function in python which can do it?

Comment: range function only works with integers

Comment: You can create a generator or a list comprehension or a regular iterator that populates your list based on the rules you define.

Comment: if you're not opposed to using 3rd party libraries, this has already been solve by `numpy` as shown [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple function that calculates the delta and create an array.

```
def n_spaced_range(x_start, x_end, n_elements):
    d = (x_end - x_start) / (n_elements-1)
    return [x_start + i*d for i in range(n_elements)]
```

Comment: Yes I know but my question is about a native function of python, as range u.u

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` does what you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.linspace(0, 2, 5)
array([0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. ])
```

If you really need it to be a list, then you can do:

```
>>> list(np.linspace(0, 2, 5))
[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
```